# Pattern doesn't remove special characters which are by themselves on a website

Tags: regex, perl

So i am currently getting a user input in the form of a URL and parsing it and then printing the other pages that website links to. The package that i am using is:

```
LWP::Simple
```

I fetch the link using user input from command line and store it in a variable. I get it using the $ARGV[0].
Then i proceed to make another variable and use the $get on the variable where i store the website.
Then i proceeded to make an array variable and apply the regex on the variable

```
/\shref="?([^\s>"]+)/gi;
```

which stored the results of the get function being used on the variable containing the website string. And then i did a foreach loop on the array to print out the results.

However, while it does print links and stuff, it also end up printing just standalone special characters such as `/` and `#` if there is nothing after them.

So like if there is something like `/blabalbla` it prints that. but if there are just standalone special characters such as `/`, `\`, or `#`, it also prints them. Any way i can modify the regex so that if the special characters don't follow a string, they should not print. New at learning perl and not so talented at regex

Comment: I can't help unless you show your code, a *real example* of a URL and the corresponding output. Your regex certainly doesn't match isolated character like that, and I think it's more likely you're misusing the regex.

Comment: What does "follow a string" mean???

Comment: @Borodin - Here it is                    http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi
                                         http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl
                                            https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8
                                                                     \                                                                          There were more links as outputs, but i removed them to fit the comment. That is using google.com. See the \ at the end

Comment: @ikegami - So if there is a link like http://blablabla, it should print that, but if its just say a forward slash or a back slash character, it shouldn't print those characters. So that special character has to be followed by a string in order to be printed. Thats what i want my regex to do

Comment: Thank you, but it's not very readable like that. Please *edit your question* to include **your program** and **the URL entered**.

Comment: @ikegami - Oh my bad. Follow by a string means it must have some alphabetical characters after that particular special character. So for instance it should be something like /google/blabla. The regex should parse out standalone characters which do no have any alphabetical characters after them. Hope this clears it up

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with your specific problem without further information, but in the mean time I suggest that you look at [`HTML::LinkExtor`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::LinkExtor) which was written for this purpose.

Here's an example code its output. It lists only `<a>` elements that have an `href` attribute.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use LWP;
use HTML::LinkExtor;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $resp = $ua->get('http://www.bbc.co.uk/');

my $extor = HTML::LinkExtor->new(undef, $resp->base);
$extor->parse($resp->decoded_content);

for my $link ($extor->links) {
  my ($tag, %attr) = @$link;
  next unless $tag eq 'a' and $attr{href};
  say $attr{href};
}
```

**output**

```
http://m.bbc.co.uk
http://www.bbc.co.uk/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/#h4discoveryzone
http://www.bbc.co.uk/accessibility/
https://ssl.bbc.co.uk/id/status
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/
http://www.bbc.com/news/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/
http://shop.bbc.com/
http://www.bbc.com/earth/
http://www.bbc.com/travel/
http://www.bbc.com/capital/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/
http://www.bbc.com/culture/
http://www.bbc.com/autos/
http://www.bbc.com/future/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/tv/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/cbbc/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/cbeebies/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/arts/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/ww1/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/learning/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/music/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/science/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/
http://www.bbc.com/earth/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/local/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/travel/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/a-z/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/#orb-footer
http://search.bbc.co.uk/search
http://www.bbc.co.uk/privacy/cookies/managing/cookie-settings.html
http://www.bbc.co.uk/locator/default/desktop/en-GB?ptrt=%2F
http://www.bbc.co.uk/#
http://www.bbc.co.uk/#
http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2643743?day=0
http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2643743?day=0
http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2643743?day=1
http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2643743?day=1
http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2643743?day=2
http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2643743?day=2
http://www.bbc.co.uk/locator/default/desktop/en-GB?ptrt=%2F
http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2643743
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-30311816
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-30311822
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-30311818
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-30282261
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-30311816
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-30291460
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-kent-30319549
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-30306106
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-30306992
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-30306145
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/local/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/england/london/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-30308694
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-30315650
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-30321504
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/live/football/29959148
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/live/snooker/29618359
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/30204433
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/cricket/30308980
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/30204434
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/30204459
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/30204511
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/28647040
http://www.bbc.co.uk/?dzf=sport
http://www.bbc.co.uk/?dzf=entertainment
http://www.bbc.co.uk/?dzf=bbcnow
http://www.bbc.co.uk/?dzf=entertainment
http://www.bbc.co.uk/?dzf=news
http://www.bbc.co.uk/?dzf=lifestyle
http://www.bbc.co.uk/?dzf=knowledge
http://www.bbc.co.uk/?dzf=sport
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/
http://www.bbc.com/news/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/
http://shop.bbc.com/
http://www.bbc.com/earth/
http://www.bbc.com/travel/
http://www.bbc.com/capital/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/
http://www.bbc.com/culture/
http://www.bbc.com/autos/
http://www.bbc.com/future/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/tv/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/cbbc/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/cbeebies/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/arts/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/ww1/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/learning/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/music/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/science/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/
http://www.bbc.com/earth/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/local/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/travel/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/a-z/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/terms/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/aboutthebbc/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/privacy/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/privacy/cookies/about
http://www.bbc.co.uk/accessibility/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/guidance/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/contact/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/bbctrust/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/complaints/
http://www.bbc.co.uk/help/web/links/
```

Comment: Thank you, i knew i could always count on you to fix my problems. I also commented above with further details, sorry i left them out in the beginning :)

Comment: How would yours be used to get user input? Like the user has to put a website in by themselves

Comment: @user2128074: In the usual way: fetch the URL from the terminal with `chomp(my $url = <>)` and then use it in `my $resp = $ua->get($url)`. Are you not interested in getting your original program to work? I'm sure it would be useful for you to understand Perl regular expressions, and I'm fairly certain the problem is in your Perl code, not in the regex, if only you would show it.

Comment: Its a class assignment and i don't want to compromise my code since teachers take a look at stack overflow as well. Is there a more private platform we can talk at where its not public? And i would have no problem showing you the code :)

Comment: @user2128074 I'm sure your teacher wouldn't mind you getting help troubleshooting a particular difficulty you're having with your assignment. What he or she *would* mind is if you copied a solution verbatim from somewhere on the web and turned it in as your own work. You can avoid that by posting your original code, saying what *specifically* you're having trouble with, and noting in the question that this is an assignment so you don't want a full solution, just some help in the right direction.

Comment: @Borodin - I proceeded to give a word explanation of what i am doing. Please let me know if it makes sense :)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Its my own code, im not worried about that. I proceeded to provide a word by word explanation of what i am trying to do

Comment: @user2128074: I've waited but I can't see *"a word explanation of what i am doing"*. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: I will close this question. Sorry for the troubles.